# Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!') - Conexion pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc

Cree un ODBC para conectar con Python con SQL Server 2012 mediante un DNS de archivo con las siguientes caracteristicas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mediante el codigo

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'Network=DBMSSOCN;'
                      'DATABASE=Datos_Sistema;'
                      'WSID=CAETAPC;'
                      'APP={Sistema operativo Microsoft® Windows®};'
                      'Trusted_Connection=Yes;'
                      'SERVER=CAETAPC\CAETASQL;')
```

obtengo el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba descargar e instalar la más reciente versión del driver de conexión para Python [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development?view=sql-server-2017).

Crea un usuario (login) y contraseña en la instancia SQL Server. Asegura que el servicio "SQL Server Browser" esté habilitado e iniciado usando SQL Server Configuration Manager. Esto es necesario porque tu instancia SQL Server es nombrada y por lo normal tiene un puerto TCP dinámico, a menos que los pongas fijo.

Luego intenta conectarte de la siguiente forma:

```
import pyodbc 
server = 'CAETAPC\CAETASQL'
database = 'Datos_Sistema' 
username = 'myusername' 
password = 'mypassword' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

o

String de conexión:

```
"DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=CAETAPC\CAETASQL;DATABASE=Datos_Sistema;UID=myuser;PWD=mypassword"
```

Lo que resulta en:

```
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=CAETAPC\CAETASQL;DATABASE=Datos_Sistema;UID=myuser;PWD=mypassword", autocommit=True)
```